# How to setup a multi primary column 1:n relationship with DBIx::Class in Perl?

Tags: perl, relationship, dbix-class

I'm writing [DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx::Class) schema classes by myself with [DBIx::Class::Candy](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx::Class::Candy). Currently I stumple around some part of an complexe database design.

I have setup most of the classes using [DBIx::Class::Relationship](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx::Class::Relationship) as template for modelling the `1:n`, `n:1` and `n:m` relationships (with one single primary key). All fine but I don't get this particular relationship running.

`Game_Users` is an `n:m` relation table between the two irrelevant tables `Games` and `Users`. `Turns` on the other hand is a "normal" table which stores single turns for the combination of game and user.

- `Game_Users` package name is `MyApp::Schema::Result::GameUser`
- `Turns` package name is `MyApp::Schema::Result::Turn`

**How to setup this multi primary column 1:n relationship with DBIx::Class in Perl?**

I like to point out that even if I show a specific example here, the generic question may be of interest by a large number of audience.

[image: Database desing: Game_Users to Turns relation]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply supply a hashref with the join expression to `has_many` and `belongs_to`. In `MyApp::Schema::Result::GameUser`:

```
__PACKAGE__->has_many(turns => 'MyApp::Schema::Result::Turn', {
    'foreign.game_id' => 'self.game_id',
    'foreign.user_id' => 'self.user_id',
});
```

In `MyApp::Schema::Result::Turn`:

```
__PACKAGE__->belongs_to(game_user => 'MyApp::Schema::Result::GameUser', {
    'foreign.game_id' => 'self.game_id',
    'foreign.user_id' => 'self.user_id',
});
```